# Query mongoDB with mongoose model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, stack

Im using the find() method to get all data from a mongoDB like this

```
exports.getPersona = function (req, res){
Persona.find( function(err, persona) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err)
                res.json(persona); // return all personas in json       
            }
        );
}
```

Im trying to do a query like this:

```
exports.getPersona = function (req, res){
Persona.find(
{
faceDetection: {
  name: "Borja"
}, function(err, persona) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err)
                res.json(persona);      
            }
        );
}
```

But i dont find nothing. My mongoose model is:

```
var faceDetectionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 faceDetection: {  
  name: String,
  surname: String,
 }
});
```

What could be the problem? Thanks a lot.

Edit: the document its a JSON like:

```
{
 "faceDetection": {  
     "name": "Borja",
     "surname": "Good"
}
```

Comment: share the saved document in mongo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your parentheses and braces are out of order. Try this below.

```
exports.getPersona = function(req, res) {
    Persona.find({
        'faceDetection.name':  "Borja"
    }, function(err, persona) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err)
        res.json(persona);
    })
}
```

Comment: add your data to the post pls.

Comment: Updated to use dot notation.Not sure if that is the problem. Can you try again ?

Comment: Yes! it was the problem. I dont know why i need to use dots, but it works fine. Thank you!